# vLookup multiple values in a single cell and return value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have 2 worksheets, the first one containing a list of bill number & amount
 for e.g

```
bill no     Amount
0001        100
0002        50
0003        80
0004        40
0005        90
-----and so on-----
```

the second sheet contains,

```
Bill No                   Amount     chq number                
0001,0002,0005    =       240        123456789
```

i want a formula in sheet one, which will look up the bill number in sheet 02 if its true then return the value in a cell

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: VLOOKUP("bill number",sheet2",2,FALSE)

the problem is sheet2, cell A2 contains 03 bill numbers in one cell and the formula  result i   #N/A

Comment: It should be something like `=VLOOKUP(0002,$A$1:$A$10,2,FALSE)` where 0002 is a bill no or a reference to a cell containing a bill no.

Comment: i want to look up a particular bill number for e.g 0001 in a single cell containing 3 or more bill number for e.g 0001,0002, 0003, 0004 and return their value

Comment: So you basically want to parse all bills N° in sheet 2 and sum up all the referring amount contained in sheet 1 to set the value of second column of sheet 2 ?

Answer (score 4):

A formula you can use is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(SEARCH(RIGHT(sheet1!billNo,4),sheet2!billNoRange),0)>0,sheet2!amountRange)
```

Basically, you’re trying to find the bill number from sheet 1 and searching for a match on the sheet 2 bill number range. You need to use the right 4 digits of the sheet1 bill number to avoid errors with the apostrophe. If you find a match in the cell, it be greater than 1 and evaluate as TRUE (or 1). If there is not match it will evaluate to FALSE (or 0) then it will multiply it by the amount range. This will give you the sum of all matches.

Hope this helps. Here’s an article on [SUMPRODUCT](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumproduct.php) if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks, did not know it was even possible.

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer was the solution, please mark it as answered. See the below link for additional information. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)